# ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API - any 2.9 beta examples available?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I found the arcgis 2.9 beta at http://servicesbeta.esri.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.9 but cannot find any beta samples.  Are they available?

Comment: There is also a 3.0 http://servicesbeta.esri.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.0/ but this doesn't mean it is a public beta - would wait for esri to make it available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kelly from ESRI has [mentioned](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/59015-2.9-beta-defect-cannot-create-a-WMS-layer#post203376) that 3.0 will be available this month.

Answer (score 2):

I would say probably not.  They don't seem to release any new samples until a version is formally released.

Of course you're welcome to ask - but I would recommend doing it over on the official [ArcGIS API for JavaScript forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/15-ArcGIS-API-for-JavaScript)